# Height of view not calculated correctly inside a weighted layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Hi I have found weird behaviour when trying to implement the following layout on android.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.75"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This piece of layout is supposed to generate a textview on the right that takes up 75% of the screen. But for some reason the height of the Textview is calculated as if the weight of its parent is 0. The text inside the view seems to wrap perfectly, but not the view itself.

Is this normal behaviour or how can I get the textview to display the correct height?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly please indent your code properly so it is easy to read. You can do that automagically in the XML editor by pressing Ctrl + Shift + F.

Secondly if you want the LinearLayouts to be 25% wide and 75% wide but fill the whole height of the screen then you need

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Thirdly, if you want the TextView to take up 75% of the screen, then why not just assign the weight directly to that and not have it wrapped in another LinearLayout?

Lastly, with weights you dont need to make the children weights add to 1. Having

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

and

```
android:layout_weight="3"
```

is also ok.

Comment: I don't want it to fill the height of the screen, I used wrap_content for a reason. I have already tried setting weight on the TextView to no avail. I am also well aware of this way of setting weights, this is my personal preference.